# Replacing bottom bracket

Tags: bottom-bracket

I have a giant fastroad, 2016 model, the BB is a FSA mega exo (bb30 press fit).
I think from the noise it is making that the BB is starting to wear out, I have done approx. 2000 miles in all weathers.
Reviews for this BB do not give good feedback with many people finding them failing after a short time.
Is there a more reliable bb30 BB that would be compatible with this bike?

Comment: BB30 Pressfit is a standard (one of many standards) so any BB30 pressfit would be compatible.  As far as a quality recommendation I suggest looking for reviews and balancing your price point  with community reviews.

Comment: This question is now 3 months old.  Can you please add an answer of your own describing what you did and how it worked for you?   Feel free to accept your own answer by clicking the tick/check box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noise was eventually found to be coming from the rear spindle, now cleaned and re-fitted.
This shows that it is important to identify the source of a problem and not just start changing things.

Answer (score 5):

BB30 and Press Fit 30 (PF30) are technically different types of BB Standard. Yes they both use 30mm bearings and 30mm spindle cranksets but the difference is that PF30 bearings are contained inside cups and these cups are pressed into the frame. This means that the two standards are not interchangeable.

Also, i have a horrible feeling that the FSA MegaExo actually uses a 24mm Spindle which will further limit you options unless you change out the whole crank.

Best bet, take it to an LBS who will ID the BB for you and offer some good alternatives

Comment: The FSA Mega Exo did at one point use a 24mm spindle, not sure if it still does, but I've got an old one (2007ish) that is def 24 mm.